# Juno - No Internet Connection

Tags: networking

I have just completed doing a clean installation of Juno. Despite having been connected to my home WiFi during the installation (from live USB), once fully installed, the OS could not connect to the Internet. I have tried connecting the laptop to the Internet via network/Ethernet cable without any success. No Wifi, no network connections whatsoever. I believe this is caused by the lack of (or incorrect) Ethernet and WiFi drivers. Since I was able to be online while booting from Live USB, I believe there are compatible drivers on the very USB that I could use. Could you please help me with locating and updating/installing the drivers? If I am not utterly mistaken, my network card is Ralink RT3290 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter 5.0.57.0.
Thanks,
Davor

P.S. I am writing this from my Win10 OS.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install driver for it. (chose ubuntu 18.04 bionic when download, eOS Juno is based on ubuntu 18.04)
this may help: [get rt3290 wireless work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760838/how-do-i-get-an-rt3290-wireless-card-to-work)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that helped was reinstalling the eOS and checking "I don't want to connect to a wifi network right now". This way the buggy/incompatible network drivers were not downloaded nor installed. 
OT: The additional problem that I had was with AppCenter not being able to connect to the Internet I resolved by reinstalling the eOS *again* and only allowing the updates for the system to be updated (I did not allow the AppCenter to update first). Waaaay disappointed with eOS.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check "use WiFi proprietary drivers" during install? If so, don't check this box and use open source drivers instead. Eventually you can uninstall proprietary drivers later from AppCenter and reboot. On my computer WiFi proprietary drivers cause a lot of problems. It's not elementaryOS fault but the Broadcom company and their shitty drivers.