# eOS Juno - HP PAVILION 15 - No WiFi after installation

Tags: release-juno, wifi, drivers, laptop

I just switched from windows to elementary OS Juno.

My Ethernet works perfectly. I only have issue with the Wifi, I've been trying a bunch of drivers and no success yet. I ran the following commands:

`iwconfig` shows:

```
lo no wireless extensions.
eno1 no wireless extensions.
```

`inxi -nx` shows:

```
Network: Card-1: Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
           port: 4000
         bus-ID: 02:00.0
             IF: N/A
          state: N/A
            mac: N/A
         Card-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCIE Gigabit Ethernet Controller
         driver: r8169
              v: 2.3LK-NAPI
           port: 3000
         bus-ID: 03:00.0
             IF: eno1
          state:
```

The laptop brand and model is: HP PAVILION 15-cs0022cl

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this thread. Maybe your problem is related to proprietary drivers  : https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16806/juno-no-internet-connection

Comment: My Ethernet works perfectly. I only have issue with the Wifi, I've been trying a bunch of drivers and no success yet.  I ran the following command.

iwconfig

lo   no wireless extensions.
eno1  no wireless extensions.

inxi -nx

Network: Card-1: Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
           port: 4000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
           IF: N/A state: N/A mac: N/A 
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCIE Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 3000 bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: eno1 state: down mac:

Comment: I had similar problem but only when I checked to install proprietary drivers for WiFi during installation process.

Comment: I've been struggling with this drivers. I dont know what else to do, with this no wireless extensions.

Comment: i dont really understand why this is marked as duplicate when its not. Not the same brand/mode or Wifi driver as the others question here asked before. Please, is there anything I can do to fix this issue, i've been struggling and no success yet.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but I think if that [question marked as original](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/17162/juno-hp-pavilion-15-no-wifi-after-installation) is very close or similar to your problem. I have also reopened the question as you have requested.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is very, *very* late but, for anyone who is still struggling with the RTL8821CE and using a Linux kernel older than 5.4, you can do this:

1. Reboot the machine and enter the UEFI/BIOS
2. Disable "Secure Boot"
3. Boot into Elementary

Once eOS is loaded:

0. Open Terminal
1. Disable validation on `mokutil`:

   ```
   sudo mokutil --disable-validation
   ```
2. Grab the Generic HWE kernel:

   ```
   sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
   sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
   ```
3. Reinstalled the `dkms` headers:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
   ```
4. Clone `tomaspinho`'s GitHub repo for the RTL8821CE:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
   ```
5. Change to the new directory and update some file permissions:

   ```
   cd rtl8821ce
   chmod +x dkms-install.sh
   chmod +x dkms-remove.sh
   ```
6. Compile the driver:

   ```
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
7. Install the driver:

   ```
   sudo ./dkms-install.sh
   ```
8. Reboot

Once this is done, you will have a fully operational wireless network adapter.

Alternatively, installing eOS6 will have support right out of the box